# Problems playing OpenArena with QJoyPad

Tags: gamepad

OpenArena looks like an awesome game, and I can't wait to give it a go.

I use a gamepad for pc games because I'm on a laptop with a trackpad. Of course I need some software to map the controller out to button clicks and mouse movements. On Windows, I use XPadder. After looking around and trying a couple, I found QJoyPad for Ubuntu. After configuring the controller, **I can verify on the desktop that the thumbstick is configured correctly** (i.e. it functions as a mouse would).

But when I start the game, **no matter which direction I move the thumbstick, I can only look right and down**. If I press up, it goes down. If I press down, it goes down. Left goes right and so does right.

Obviously, this makes it very hard to play OpenArena in a way that could be described as entertaining.

I've checked to make sure 'free look' is ticked in the menu settings. It is.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I am still experiencing this problem, and still hoping someone can help me find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with my `mouse.lyt`:

```
# QJoyPad 4.1 Layout File

Joystick 1 {
Axis 1: gradient, maxSpeed 2, mouse+h
Axis 2: gradient, maxSpeed 2, mouse+v
Axis 3: gradient, maxSpeed 2, mouse+h
Axis 4: gradient, maxSpeed 2, mouse+v
Button 1: key 111
Button 2: mouse 3
Button 3: key 116
Button 4: mouse 1
Button 5: key 115
Button 6: key 117
Button 7: key 110
Button 8: key 112
Button 9: key 36
Button 10: key 36
}
```